# Versions section should not allow submission without a table

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

I was browsing documentation and noticed there's a Notepad++ documentation section. Being a frequent user of Notepad++, I went to see what other users have added so far. I started by checking if they'd added versions.

[They did.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/40451) But not correctly.

I was pretty surprised to see this edit was able to be proposed, considering there is *zero* table formatting in this proposed change. The sidebar when you edit versions actually says the section must be formatted as a table.

> Versions must be formatted as a table, where the first column is the version name and the last column is a YYYY-MM-DD style release date.

After a quick chat with Jon Ericson, [he thinks it's strange as well](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31987632#31987632) and suggested this should be brought up here.

I'm not sure if it's a *bug* or just something that's not currently validated. If it *isn't* a bug, I propose a versions change should not be able to be submitted without at least one table in the versions section.

Comment: I fully agree, although it would be nice to be able to enter partial dates :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That it would. Thankfully, in _fixing_ these versions, I haven't run across a need for partial dates myself, but I've seen elsewhere where they would be incredibly useful. (I still have a good 75+ versions left to grab dates for, though, so I might run into one somewhere. I doubt it, the release dates of Notepad++ seem really well documented on the site.)

Comment: Are these hundred versions of Notepad++ useful to list? Is actually anything in the documentation for Notepad++ useful?

Comment: @Matsemann The point of this questions is not Notepad++. That should be discussed either on another Meta question or in chat. The point of this question is that the version section should be validated on submission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the latest build, an edit that modifies the versions section can only have tables (and headings, if the are multiple tables) as the top-level elements in their markdown.

Old drafts and whatnot aren't updated (as there's no sensible way to fix that data up), but future edits that modify those sections will have to fix the formatting in order to be submitted for review.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of problem which is meaning that edits that do not change the version section are still being rejected under this new checking system. Functionally this makes small changes to other areas of the documentation less likely or impossible (given: "no sensible way to fix that data up", if I'm understanding you correctly...), and may serve to decrease the quality of the documentation available on site.