# Is there a bug with Versions tables editing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I am trying to edit the [versions table](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/217/getting-started-with-html#t=201612210058227490171&a=versions) that already exists on the HTML documentation.

After doing my amends I received the following error:

> **Versions section only allows headings and tables**

So I thought there was something wrong with my edit, retracted it and went in to edit again.

Even when there are no changes and you try to save it produces the same error message:

> **Versions section only allows headings and tables**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Versions section should not allow submission without a table](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329970/versions-section-should-not-allow-submission-without-a-table)

Comment: @EngineerDollery there is already a table there though.

Comment: Read the answer on the linked question. If it's not a duplicate let us know why.

Comment: The error message does not provide any helpful suggestion, even reading the linked answer I cannot see what exactly needs to change with the table in its current state?

Comment: Ahhh, I know exactly what's going on here... fix incoming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest build.

Subtlety in CommonMark parsing - link references (like `[0]: http://google/`) are "blocks".  An [earlier fix for version section validation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329970/versions-section-should-not-allow-submission-without-a-table) restricted the top level blocks that were legal, but omitted link references as permitted blocks.

This only affected versions with non-inline links, such as the one you noticed.

Comment: I received the same problem today, but for horizontal rules (`----`). Is it possible to fix that one too?