# "Versions section only allows headings and tables" error when editing the docs

Tags: bug, documentation

I get this error when trying to edit "remarks" in a document post:

> Versions section only allows headings and tables

I get this error even though I did not even edit the version section—just the "remark" section. What's going on? Is this some bug, or do I have to do something else when editing to not get that error?

Comment: Probably overzealous checking as [part of this fix](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339980/3614835).

Comment: Which topic are you trying to edit when you get this error?

Comment: @AdamLear here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/119150?filter-tags=java Look at the comment I made at the bottom.

Comment: I also tried the same, and I did not added anything in the version section. I tried updating the existing example by editing it. But while savings it gives me the same error.

Comment: I can't add anything to [NetLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/netlogo/3105/getting-started-with-netlogo) either, I added notes in an earlier version and feel that it would be incomplete without them because the version history is kind of incomplete.

Comment: I experienced this as well. I had to dig deep into the past of [the worst documented programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP#History) to find version release dates in order to proceed.